# How to know which div I clicked to change it's content?

Tags: jquery, html, selected, each

I'm achieving a "delete comments system", a "delete div" near to each comment, but I'm stuck on how to know in which  I clicked on "Delete" button after a jquery post function runs? and then how to show "deleted" word appeares in place of the last "delete" clicked on?

```
<script ..>
$(".click).click(function(){
$.post("do.php",{...},function(data){/* I'm here*/})
});
</script>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("select * from ...");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result )){
?>
<div class="comment">
..
<a href="#" class="click">Delete</a>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>" class="comm">
</div>
```

Any help will be greatfully appreciated.
Salutations.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    var me = this;
    $.post("do.php",{...},function(data){ alert(me); )
});
```

Comment: Euuh, no, that did not help me, I did: $.post("do.php",{...},function(data){ $(this).html("deleted"); ) but nothing changed! hey, further details Jakub is appreciated!

Comment: @Nadj are you sure that do.php is returning success?

Comment: @Nadj - do not use `this` inside your callback, use `me` - it is the element you clicked. You need to get the commentId attribute value from it.

Comment: maniator, yes, it works correctly, till know, I did not talk about what it returns, I want just something to happen after click on "delete" button, right??

Comment: Jakub Konecki, I did, post function works, but "delete" stay as it is, not showing "deleted" instead, who do u suggest?

Comment: @Nadj - you need to find your div based on `me`. `me` is the link you've clicked. Loot at jQuery `sibling`, `val` methods.

Comment: at this point would it not be something like 'var yourDivElement = me.parent()' to find parent, 'yourDivElement.empty()' to remove whatever is there, then yourDivElement.append('deleted') to add deleted, something likethe suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the value of the class in your input element.

```
<input type="hidden" class="<?php echo $idComm; ?>">
```

Although I would put the commentId in a value attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $idComm; ?>" class="commentId">
```

Because your click function is attached to the a you will need to use jquery to get it

```
$(".click).click(function(){
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent();    // get parent div
    var commentId = parentDiv.find('input#commentId').val();  // get comment id 
    $.post(
       "do.php",
       { "commentId" : commentId },   // post comment id to server to extract from POST variable
       function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
           parentDiv.empty();       // Removes whats inside your div
           parentDiv.append('deleted')    // adds deleted inside the div
       }
   );
});
```

JQuery ajax makes all this simpler but I am answering the question asked

not tested so there might be typos

Comment: Ok whatsthebeef, I'll try it!